# Typescript: how to pass in a generic function as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

At the moment, I have a function that successfully finds one element in a given array and shifts it to the front. But I want to define a function that given an array of values, it will iterate through these, find them and shift them to the front of an array (which is passed as another parameter). The part that I'm stuck on right now is, the finding aspect. Each value that is passed (to be shifted to the front) needs to be found in the array first.

To do this part, I wanted to have that find parameter as a function parameter.

My first attempt was something along these lines (I know this does not work):

```
public shiftObjectsToStart(array: Array<any>, itemsToShift: Array<any>, findIndex: (...args: any[]) => number): void {
    itemsToShift.forEach(element => {
        const idx = findIndex(); // This needs to be changed/fixed/HELP
        if (idx !== -1){
            this.shiftObjectToStart(array, idx);
        }
    });
}
```

I am sure that I'm getting my wires crossed in my approach to make the function more generic feeling by making the find aspect a function.

Keep in mind that I'm mostly using these Array functions with custom defined objects, whereby finding instances of said object in a collection will vary.

**My code MUST be ES5 friendly**

The full array utils service can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/richflee/9fead9819ab016f27ee9582326858f90

Comment: If your code must be ES5 friendly, why are you attempting to solve it in a way that is not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I'm guessing you want a predicate function for your `findIndex` function. You don't need to find the index by the way, you could do it with two arrays (one with the shifted values, the other without the shifted values) and just concat at the end.

Comment: Ok. At the moment I'm using `splice` to cut out the relevant items to shift. But that requires the index. Secondly, the items to shift array won't necessarily be of the same type as what is in the original array.